# If $A^3 =0$, what is the determinant of $(A-3I)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

From $A^3 = 0$, I can conclude that A must be singular. But how to proceed from there?

Comment: It's $ -27/\det(A^2 + 3A + 9)$

Comment: @Azlif Can you share how you came to this solution??

Comment: Is $A$ a $3\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: @Arthur a general solution for a $n$x $n$ matrix would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A^3=0$, $A$ is a nilpotent matrix and all its eigenvalues are $0$. Now we can see that eigenvalues of $A-3I$ are $-3,-3,\ldots, -3$ ($n-$times). For, let $X$ be an eigenvector of $A$ such that $AX=0$. Then $(A-3I)X=AX-3IX=-3X$. Therefore $-3$ is an eigenvalue of $A-3I$. Since Det$(A-3I)=$product of eigenvalues, Det$(A-3I)=(-3)^n$.

Here one thing that should be noticed that the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $-3$ is $n$. Using the Jordan canonical form you can see this.

Comment: Your note about algebraic multiplicity is wrong (the algebraic multiplicity is $n$), and the Jordan form is unnecessary. And there is no need for the vector $X$. The determinant is the product of all eigenvalues (repeated according to algebraic multiplicity) and that's it.

Comment: Why wrong, since field is not mentioned that's why I am consdering it as $\mathbb{C}.$ I need the vector $X$ to show that $-3$ is an eigen value.

Comment: You don't need to consider the field to be $\mathbb{C}$. If $A^3=0$, then the minimal polynomial divides $t^3$, which means the characteristic polynomial is $(-1)^nt^n$. No need for eigenvectors or for Jordan forms, or to consider the field.

Comment: And "since you don't tell me what the field is I'm going to assume it's $\mathbb{C}$" is what is called an "unwarranted assumption", which is usually considered a wrong thing to assume. So, yes, wrong.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If the field is not given, then usually we consider $\mathbb{C}$. Also since eigen values are real so my result is true.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For algebraic multiplicity we need Jordan canonical form. There are more ways to prove this, but I choose this.

Comment: If you "usually consider $\mathbb{C}$" in the absence of that assumption, then you usually make unwarranted assumptions. Doing so routinely doesn't excuse it, it just means you are making unwarranted assumptions as a matter of course. As to your final comment, it's nonense. You do **not** need the Jordan form for the algebraic multiplicity. Since the minimal polynomial is a divisor of $t^3$, the only irreducible factors in the characteristic polynomial is $t$, so the only eigenvalue is $0$ with multiplicity $n$. No Jordan form needed. So don't say you "need it" unless you want to be wrong.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  I am using Jordan canonical form tor the eigen values of $A-3I$ and that is not nonsense

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to assume you are working over $\mathbb{C}$; you also do not need the Jordan canonical form (though such a matrix would have one over any field, since the minimal polynomial splits).

Since $A^3=0$, that means that $A$ satisfies the polynomial $t^3$. This means the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $t^3$. Thus, the only irreducible factor of the minimal polynomial, regardless of the field you are working over, is $t$.

Since every irreducible factor of the characteristic polynomial is an irreducible factor of the minimal polynomial (over *any* field), then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is necessarily equal to $(-1)^nt^n$, where $n$ is the size of $A$ (that is, $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix). Thus, the eigenvalue $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $n$.

Now, if a matrix $B$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, repeated with algebraic multiplicity, then $\alpha B + \beta I$ has eigenvalues $\alpha\lambda_1+\beta$, $\alpha\lambda_2+\beta,\ldots,\alpha\lambda_n+\beta$.

Thus, the eigenvalue of $A-3I$ is $-3$, with algebraic multiplicity $n$.

Now, the determinant of a matrix is the constant term of its characteristic polynomial (which is $\det(A-tI)$). This would be the product of all its eigenvalues (with algebraic multiplicity) over an algebraic closure of the field of definition; but since here we already have that the characteristic polynomial is $(-1)^n(t+3)^n$, it follows that the determinant of $A-3I$ is $(-1)^n3^n$.

No Jordan forms needed. No complex field assumption needed.

Comment: Why are you using the result if $B$ has eigen value etc. If you wants to prove about the algebraic multiplicity then you need the Jordan canonocal form

Comment: @MANI: No, you don’t need the Jordan canonical form to prove the claim about the eigenvalues or their multiplicity, and your continued insistence that you do does not make it so: it just proves you don’t know what you are talking about but nonetheless you think you can instruct others. I’m using the fact that if I know what the eigenvalues of $A$ are (and I do, **without using the Jordan form**), then I know what the eigenvalues of $A-3I$ are (and more generally, of $\beta A + \mu I$ for any $\beta$ and $\mu$). If you don’t get it, *ask*, instead of getting offended that you are called out.

Comment: I am really sorry sir for misbehavior. But really I do not know that how we can show this. Actually the only thing that is coming in mind is Jordan canonical form to prove about the multiplicity. If somehow I hurt you, please forgive me and give me some hints so that I can easily see that how can we claim that if eigen values of $\beta A+\mu I$.

Comment: @MANI: You aren’t “hurting” me, you are just making a fool and a nuisance of yourself. I *explain* how you get the multiplicity, but you aren’t listening because you are too busy defending your false assertion that the Jordan form is needed. *Every* irreducible factor of the characteristic polynomial divides the minimal polynomial. The minimal polynomial divides *any* polynomial satisfied by $A$. Since $A$ satisfies $t^3$, the minimal polynomial is either $t$, $t^2$, or $t^3$. Which means the characteristic polynomial *must* be $(-1)^nt^n$. That’s all you need to get the alg. multiplicity.

Comment: Sorry for all the stuff sir, Now I got the point. Really sorry for all the stuff I did. I was not doing this deliberately, it happens just because of my wrong attitude. Again sorry and thank you for your continuous comments rather than avoiding me for continuous misbehavior.